# UDP socket using select() stops receiving after first iteration and data inequality

Tags: sockets, select, networking, udp, server

My objective is to receive the datagrams, which are continuosly sent by client (server_address_ob) every 10 mili seconds and send this received datagram to another server (server_address_hm) using UDP sockets. This should be done continuosly as my program should act like a middle man between server_Address_ob and server_address_hm . I wrote this code(below) in C with some references from internet using select()

The Problem with code :

1) data received and data sent are not same

```
bsnayak@ubuntu:~/Desktop/learn$ ./ar4

Main server waiting for client to respond...

(192.168.37.1 , 1901) rcvd: 0x1ae50990

(0.0.0.0 , 0) sent: 0x1ae69030
```

2) why the address is 0.0.0.0 ,0 although the socket is created here with following definition

```
 server_address_hmi.sin_port = htons(1902);
 server_address_hmi.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.37.134");
```

3)  Although the program runs but after receiving and sending once , the program doesnot receive any    packets or send them anymore.

```
    //Main SERVER
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/select.h>//use select() for multiplexing
#include <sys/fcntl.h> // for non-blocking

#define MAX_LENGTH 100000
#define PORT 1901

/* Select() params
 * int select(int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
 * FD_SET(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_CLR(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_ISSET(int fd, fd_set *set);
 * FD_ZERO(fd_set *set);
*/

void error(char *message)
{
    perror(message);
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{

  // select parameters declared
  fd_set original_socket;
  fd_set original_stdin;
  fd_set readfds;
  fd_set writefds;
  struct timeval tv;
  int numfd, numfd2;

  // socket parameters declared
  int socket_fd_ob, socket_fd_hm;
  int bytes_read, bytes_sent;
  char address_length, address_length2;
  char recieve_data[MAX_LENGTH];
  char send_data[MAX_LENGTH];
  struct sockaddr_in server_address_ob, server_address_hm, client_address;
  int z = 0;

  //Socket creation done separately for both OB and HM communications
  if ((socket_fd_ob = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) 
  {
      error("socket()");
  }
  if ((socket_fd_hm = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) 
  {
      error("socket()");
  }


  fcntl(socket_fd_ob, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //set socket to non-blocking
  fcntl(socket_fd_hm, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); //set socket to non-blocking

  // clear the set ahead of time
  FD_ZERO(&original_socket);
  FD_ZERO(&original_stdin);
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_ZERO(&writefds);

  // add our descriptors to the set (0 - stands for STDIN)
  FD_SET(socket_fd_ob, &original_socket);//instead of 0 put socket_fd_ob
  FD_SET(socket_fd_ob, &readfds);
  FD_SET(0,&original_stdin);
  FD_SET(0, &writefds);

  // since we got s2 second, it's the "greater", so we use that for
  // the n param in select()
  numfd  = socket_fd_ob + 1;
  numfd2 = socket_fd_hm + 1;


  // wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 10.5 secs)
  tv.tv_sec = 1;
  tv.tv_usec = 500000;

  server_address_ob.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address_ob.sin_port = htons(1901);
  server_address_ob.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.37.1");
  bzero(&(server_address_ob.sin_zero),sizeof(server_address_ob));

  server_address_hm.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_address_hm.sin_port = htons(1902);
  server_address_hm.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.37.134");
  bzero(&(server_address_ob.sin_zero),sizeof(server_address_hm));

  // Bind socket to the particular addresses

  if (bind(socket_fd_ob,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_ob, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
      error("bind()");
  }

  if (bind(socket_fd_hm,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_hm, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
  {
      error("bind()");
  }

  address_length  = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
  address_length2 = sizeof(struct sockaddr);

  printf("\nMain server waiting for client to respond...\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  while (1)
  {
    readfds = original_socket;
    writefds = original_stdin;//problem
    int recieve = select(numfd, &readfds, &writefds,/*NULL,*/ NULL, &tv);
    int sent    = select(numfd2, &readfds, &writefds,/*NULL,*/ NULL, &tv);

    if (recieve == -1 || sent == -1) 
    {
      perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
    } 
    else if (recieve == 0 || sent == 0) 
    {
      printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 1.5 seconds.\n");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // one or both of the descriptors have data
        if (FD_ISSET(socket_fd_ob, &readfds)) //if set to read
        { 
          FD_CLR(socket_fd_ob, &readfds);
          bytes_read = recvfrom(socket_fd_ob,recieve_data,MAX_LENGTH,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &address_length); 

     for (z = 0; z < bytes_read; ++z) {
     FD_ISSET(socket_fd_hm, &writefds);
          FD_CLR(socket_fd_hm, &writefds);
          //recvfrom speech recognition client and decide what to send to HM accordingly..
          send_data[bytes_read] = recieve_data[bytes_read];
          //block call, will wait till client enters something, before proceeding
          //send the corresponding to HM
          bytes_sent = sendto(socket_fd_hm,send_data,strlen(send_data)+1,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address_hm, &address_length2); 
          fflush(stdout);
          }                  
          recieve_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer
          send_data[bytes_read] = '\0'; //add null to the end of the buffer

          printf("\n(%s , %d) rcvd: %02x\n",inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr),ntohs(client_address.sin_port),recieve_data);
          printf("\n(%s , %d) sent: %02x\n",inet_ntoa(server_address_hm.sin_addr),ntohs(server_address_hm.sin_port),send_data);
        }




    } //end else
  }//end while

  close (socket_fd_ob);
  return 0;
}
```

Hope to get a solution to my questions. Thank you for helping in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't testing for errors in `select()` correctly. You can get an error in one of them. The test should be `recieve == -1 || sent == -1`, but I cannot imagine why you are calling `select()` twice at all, or even why you're using two sockets. You only *need* one select. Try it that way, you'll probably drive out some other bugs.

NB You can't rely on the second socket descriptor being greater than the first just because of the order you created the sockets in. You must test, or use `max()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I used two socket because whith one i am receiving datas from a client and through another socket i am sending data to another server. This program is playing as a middle man between a client and server.

Comment: Hi.. I wanted that after the bytes from client 1 is received 

    bytes_read =     recvfrom(socket_fd_ob,recieve_data,MAX_LENGTH,0,(struct sockaddr     *)&client_address, &address_length);    

I want to store it in send_data and send this to socket socket_fd_hm. 

Do you have any suggetion what needed to be changed on my codes? 

NB: I checked with Wireshark message is received but it is not sent to the address of server_address_hm. It seems there is problem with sendto. 

Thnak you

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use the same socket for both purposes. They're full-duplex. I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: How can i bind the server2 address if i use one socket? It gives binding error.. Currently i am using 2 sockets one for ClientA and other for CLient B(actually acting as a server)

Comment: Why do you think you need to bind two addresses?

Comment: Because i want this program to run as a middle man between another server and a client..

Comment: You can accomplish that with a single UDP socket.

Comment: Can you suggest how should i chose the IP addresses? I tried with creating a single select socket but i can see in wireshark it is receiving datas but sending is not done.. !! Should all IP be in the 127.0.0.1 domain or we need to configure them differently?